# What are Red's Pokemon's Awakening Values (AVs)?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

Pokemon Trainer Red is one of the final opponents in the game and arguably the hardest to beat. Some trainers in the games have AVs in some stats making them harder, such as the Master trainers. [A list of the Master trainers' AVs are here.](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/mastertrainers.shtml) Red has AVs, but they are missing from thist list. What AVs do Red's Pokemon's have?

This knowledge would help beat Red, particularly when using an underleveled team and saving the effort of grinding levels. I would guess that all his Pokemon have AVs in more than one stat. From battling Red multiple times, I suspect that these are some of his AV investments:

- Pikachu has Attack
- Machamp has Speed
- Snorlax has Defence
- Lapras has Attack
- Lapras has Speed. My starter Eevee outsped Arcanine but not Lapras, despite Arcanine having a lower base Speed stat than Lapras (95 vs 60). This is only possible with Lapras having more AVs in Speed than Arcanine.

Comment: Man, even with a bounty, nobody has been able to answer this :/

Comment: :( I’d be willing to accept an answer that lists all the stats with AVs without necessarily stating the AVs exactly - it’s progress